# Options to override bootstrap's defaults

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I notice that Bootstrap's `form-control` class no longer keeps the `display: inline-block` one the screen width gets smaller than 768px. In order to override this I had to set

```
.form-control {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Is this the only one around CSS rules? Do I have to use `!important`? I tried giving the element another class, like `display-inline-block` with the same CSS as the above, except without the `!important`, but it didn't work. It feels weird to override Bootstrap with `!important` because I was taught to try to avoid using it, but is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/less/forms.less) the `display: block;` declaration is applied to the `.form-control` css class at the root, so, in order to override it, should be enough putting `.form-control { display: inline-block; }` after the bootstrap inlude:

```html
<html>
      <head>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        
        <style>
          .form-control { 
            display: inline-block;
          }
        </style>
        
      </head>
      <body>

        <!-- INSPECT THIS ELEMENT -->
        <input class="form-control" />

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this didn't work when I placed it into my master.css, which is bundled into my bundle.js through webpack, which is a script I run after the link to bootstrap. why is that?

Comment: actually this didn't work even when I did as you showed with the css placed inside the head tag

Comment: You need to control the order of how modules are bundled via webpack, have a check in the `inspector`... My solution **MUST** work because css stands for `CASCADE style sheet`.